# Ant: override default target/artifacts directory

Tags: ant

I am looking for property or settings which will override the default `target/artifacts` directory when we issue ant build command.

We have couple of modules and when we issue `ant build`, each modules creates artifacts under `./target/artifacts` directory.

I want to override the output to custom directory. some thing like

```
./target/small/artifacts
./target/big/artifacts
```

based on the property which specifies which configuration to build. Either big/small.

Please let me know if there is any property/settings which can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use normal Ant properties?

```
<!-- Default value if none specified. -->
<property name="artifacttarget" value="small"/>

<target ...>
  <mkdir dir="target/${artifacttarget}/artifacts"/>
  ...
```

Then invoke:

```
ant -Dartifacttarget=small
ant -Dartifacttarget=big
```